# Blazor WebAssembly: localized strings fail to load when setting a different CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, blazor, webassembly

I want to localize the strings in a Blazor WebAssembly app, but I want to keep the date and number notation fixed to en-US. The problem is that when I set DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture (which should control the localized strings) to something else than DefaultThreadCurrentCulture (which should control the date and number) the localized strings from the resx files are no longer found. If I set both to the same value (thus e.g. both en-US or both nl-BE), everything works as expected.

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Is this a bug or am I missing something? Below is a part of my test code with comments about which combinations of CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture work or not work.
I put this code right at the start in the Main method.

```
private const string English = "en-US";
private const string Dutch = "nl-BE";
[...]
switch (combination)
{
    case Combination.English:
        // Works fine
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(English);
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(English);
        break;
    case Combination.Dutch:
        // Works fine
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Dutch);
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Dutch);
        break;
    case Combination.DutchEnglish:
        // Only the date and the float work (CurrentCulture)
        // Resourcestrings are not found
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Dutch);
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(English);
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Dutch);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(English);
        break;
    case Combination.EnglishDutch:
        // Only the date and the float work (CurrentCulture)
        // Resourcestrings are not found
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(English);
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Dutch);
        break;
}
```

And to be complete, the localized contents of the Index.razor page:

```
@page "/"
@using System.Globalization
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<Index> localizedStrings


<table style="border-spacing: 0.5em; border: 1px solid black;">
    <thead style="text-align:left;">
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Localization source</th>
            <th>Localization value (Current/DefaultThread)</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Expectation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Localized string</td>
            <td>CurrentUICulture</td>
            <td>@CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture / @CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture</td>
            <td>@localizedStrings["HelloWorld"]</td>
            <td>nl-BE: Dag wereld!, en-US: Hello world!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Localized float</td>
            <td>CurrentCulture</td>
            <td>@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture / @CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture</td>
            <td>@(0.5)</td>
            <td>nl-BE should be with comma, en-US with point</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Localized long date</td>
            <td>CurrentCulture</td>
            <td>@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture / @CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture</td>
            <td>@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()</td>
            <td>nl-BE: zaterdag 22 augustus 2020, en-US: Saturday, August 22, 2020</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I print the cultures on Index.razor, all values are always set as expected. So it isn't the case that those values are not propagated to the razor page:

```
<h3>Current cultures</h3>
<p>CurrentCulture: @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture</p>
<p>CurrentUICulture: @CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture</p>
<p>DefaultThreadCurrentCulture: @CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture</p>
<p>DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture: @CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture</p>
```

Comment: Try placing the `CultureInfo` settings to your controller methods for each instead of `Main()`.

Comment: @donggas90 Hi, I'm talking about the default (unhosted) Blazor WebAssembly app you get when you start one in Visual Studio. As far as I can tell there are no controllers. Can you specify a little more what you mean? Do you mean setting it in Pages/Index.razor?

Comment: The `CultureInfo` comes from basically running system(server) and then request's header. I cannot sure the WebAssembly taking client's region as `CultureInfo` but try placing before calling related functions.

Comment: @donggas90 I added ```protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("nl-BE");
    }``` to Index.razor, but that doesn't seem to be be picked up. I also edited the question to clarify that the cultures do get propagated to Index.razor as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is a bug that is being addressed in .net5.0-preview8 - which should be out this week, hopefully!

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24174

EDIT:
It seems I was wrong about this fixing your issue - it doesn't.
From quick testing using aspnetcore 5 preview 8, it seems the only time localization works is if both currentculture and currentuiculture match.

Comment: I don't completely understand the bug you linked (never worked with ICU), but I'll take your word for it and mark my question as answered.